# Why is a "double-cancellative" operation so weird?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations, associativity, magma

Let $A = \{ \{0\}, \{0,1\} \}$.
Let $\bar{A}$ be the family of sets generated by the Cartesian product on $A$.

This is a magma $(\bar{A}, \times)$ that has what I am calling a "double cancellative" operation, because if $A \times B = C \times D$, then $A = C$ and $B = D$.

Is there a good, deep reason why an operation that is "double cancellative" seems to break every single property we are usually interested in?

If we ask that a magma $(M,*)$ be associative with double cancellation, it's the trivial group. If we ask for commutativity, it's the trivial group. If we ask that it have inverses, it's the trivial group. If we even ask for an identity, it's the trivial group. If we ask for a quasigroup, it's the trivial group, if we ask the operation to be medial, it's the trivial group, left or right semimedial, trivial group, distributive, it's the trivial group. I can't seem to ask anything of a double-cancellative operation without destroying everything!

But, it's not like this is such a strange idea, since Cartesian product is a common operation. Why is this property so degenerative on an algebraic structure?

My intuition hints that double-cancellation is a very "restrictive" property (we're exactly saying that for any $A$, $B$, $A * B$ can't be represented as any other product of two elements), and so any other property being placed innately on the operation is either already implied by double-cancellation or contrary to it. Is there a way to show this?

Comment: It might be worth thinking of the double-cancellative operation as an _ordered pair_ operation; rather than forming $A\times B$, you're forming the ordered pair $\langle A,B\rangle$. It's not too surprising then that anything that 'collapses' this pair forces a trivial structure.

Comment: Thank you Steven, but what do you mean by 'collapses' here?

Comment: e.g., for there to be an identity then it must be the case that $A = \langle A, I\rangle$, but this (in effect) violates Foundation.  Likewise, for associativity we have $\langle A, \langle B, C\rangle\rangle = \langle\langle A,B\rangle,C\rangle$, which then implies $\langle A, B\rangle = A$, which once again violates Foundation. Etc.